# Best way to pass sensitive variables on click event?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables, button

I am looking for a secure way of passing sensitive variables to a php file via ajax. At the moment i have been using data attributes but the values can be changed using something like firebug.

HTML:

```
<div class="strip">
    <?php
        if($hide == 0) {
            echo '<h2 class="action" data-type="1" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-action="0">Hide Business</h2>';
        }
        if($hide == 1) {
            echo '<h2 class="action" data-type="1" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-action="1">Un-Hide Business</h2>';
        }
    ?>
    <h2 class="action" data-type="1" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-action="2">Delete Business</h2>
</div>
```

JavaScript/JQuery:

```
$(".action").click(function() {
    var type = $(this).data("type");
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var action = $(this).data("action");

    $.ajax({
        url : 'assets/php/confirm.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : "type="+type+"&action="+action+"&ids="+id,
        success : function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['type'], $_POST['action'], $_POST['ids'])) {
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    $ids = explode(",", $_POST['ids']);
    $count = count($ids);

    if($type == 0) {
        if($action == 1) {
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM deals WHERE id=?");
        } else {
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE deals SET hide=0 WHERE id=?");
        }
    } else {
        if($action == 1) {
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM businesses WHERE id=?");
        } else {
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE businesses SET hide=0 WHERE id=?");
        }
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $ids[$i]);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
    echo 'Success updated '.$_POST['ids'];
}
```

The variables that need to be secure are the data-type, data-id, data-action values. Reason being i dont want the wrong database entries being deleted.
I dont know of any alternatives, so any help would be great.

Comment: Anything client side must be considered as public, so no sensitive data should be send to client side without any server side check. So check server side that user is allowed to do what he wants regarding these sensible datas

Comment: Anything can be tampered with, not only data attribute. You can send request event without a browser, so...just use the proper validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop the user changing them, then you can't get them from the user at all. Store the data on the server instead.

If you want to limit what values you'll accept from the user, then limit them on the server. Perform authentication and authorization. Make sure the values being changed are ones the logged in user is allowed to change.

Comment: How can i check whether it has been changed form its original value? the 'id' & 'type' i can cross check with database values but the action i dont know how i would go about it.

Comment: Short of storing the original value (in which case there's no point in sending the values to the client and back) you can't check if it has been changed from its original value. You can only check if the value the server receives is acceptable (by whatever conditions you want to set to describe what acceptable is).

Answer (score 0):

As your code on the client - inside the browser - can not be hidden, you should secure the connection between client and web server - use [SSL/TSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer) for that...

Comment: The value can be changed before it is sent though?

Comment: Anything on the client can be changed - if you want to prevent it do not send it to the client...